# Infinite loop - Waiting for the SIGRTMIN

Tags: c, signals, handler

I'm trying to use the signal SIGRTMIN, in order to do_stuff when it gives me permission. It's my first time working with signals. The problem is that I'm stuck in

```
while (go == 0){printf("Waiting\n");}
```

This is my code:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

volatile sig_atomic_t go = 0;

void handler (int sig)
{   
    go = 1;
    signal (sig, handler);
}

void do_stuff (void)
{
    puts ("Doing stuff while waiting for alarm....");
}

int main (void)
{
    int i=0;

    signal (SIGRTMIN, handler);

    while(i<5){
        while (go == 0){printf("Waiting\n");}
        do_stuff();
        i++;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Can you help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you send `SIGRTMIN` to the process (e.g using `kill`)?

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean, but i haven't done anything else except of compiling and running the upper code.

Comment: Well, that would be the problem...you waited for a signal that didn't arrive!

Comment: How can I send a signal? You mean something like Ctrl-C?

Comment: Use `kill`. It's good for more than just killing processes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the SIGRTMIN signals sent from somewhere; it won't respond to the signal until it is sent.  The simplest thing is to have it send itself signals, so here's a mildly revised version of your code.

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>

#ifndef SIGRTMIN
#define SIGRTMIN SIGUSR1
#endif

volatile sig_atomic_t go = 0;

static
void handler(int sig)
{
    go = 1;
    signal(sig, handler);
}

static
void do_stuff(void)
{
    puts("Doing stuff while waiting for alarm....");
    go = 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    signal(SIGRTMIN, handler);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        while (go == 0)
        {
            puts("Waiting...");
            struct timespec t = { .tv_sec = 0, .tv_nsec = 300000000 };
            nanosleep(&t, 0); 
            kill(getpid(), SIGRTMIN);
        }
        do_stuff();
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Example run:

```
Waiting...
Doing stuff while waiting for alarm....
Waiting...
Doing stuff while waiting for alarm....
Waiting...
Doing stuff while waiting for alarm....
Waiting...
Doing stuff while waiting for alarm....
Waiting...
Doing stuff while waiting for alarm....
```

Not very exciting output, but it is at least working.  The `nanosleep()` sleeps for 0.3 seconds.